# VBA Formula based on termination date to last row

Tags: excel, vba

I was returning values at some stage but now nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

I've pulled this out of a larger code to test but am basically trying to calculate a value off a termination date in a column and present the new value in a separate column.

My code:

```
Sub IfTest()
    Dim dtToday As Date
        dtToday = Date
    Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim TermDate As Range
    
    Set TermDate = Worksheets("File Name").UsedRange
    
    For Each TermDate In Worksheets("File Name").Range("AB" & lastRow)
    
        If TermDate > dtToday Then
            TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "1"
            
        ElseIf TermDate = dtToday Then
            TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "1"
            
        ElseIf TermDate < dtToday Then
            TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "0"
        End If
    Next TermDate
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try deleting line `Set TermDate = Worksheets("File Name").UsedRange` and do `For Each TermDate In Worksheets("File Name").Range("AB2:AB" & lastRow)`

Comment: Amazing - It worked, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You means like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IfTest()

Dim dtToday As Date
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim TermDate As Range

dtToday = Date
lastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
Set TermDate = Worksheets("File Name").Range("AB2:AB" & lastRow)

For Each TermDate In TermDate
    
    If TermDate > dtToday Then
        TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "1"
            
    ElseIf TermDate = dtToday Then
        TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "1"
            
    ElseIf TermDate < dtToday Then
        TermDate.Offset(0, 5).Value = "0"
    End If
    
Next TermDate
    
End Sub
```